# Class Implementing Two Interfaces which Define the Same Method

Tags: c#, oop, interface-implementation

```
//inteface i11 
 public interface i11
    {
        void m11();
    }
//interface i22
    public interface i22
    {
         void m11();
    }

//class ab implements interfaces i11 and i22
    public class ab : i11, i22
    {
        public void m11()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("class");
        }
    }
```

now when in Main() method we create an object of class ab
which interface method will get called please explain all.

Comment: It wouldn't make a difference since both interfaces declare a `void m11();` which it implements?

Comment: If this is a real example, I would really advice you to do something about your class, interface and method names. Having descriptive names help readability tremendously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interfaces merely say "Anything that implements this interface can be sure to have these methods". 
If you think about it in that context, you'll see that it doesn't call the interface's method; rather, it merely implements the method calls required.

Answer (score 9):

There's only one method implementation, so obviously that gets called, regardless of the type of the reference.  I.E.:

```
i11 o = new ab();
o.m11();
```

and

```
i22 o = new ab();
o.m11();
```

are effectively the same.

`ab.m11` satisfies the signature of the method in both interfaces.  Also, you're not using [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), so that isn't a factor.

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing the implementation of an interface with the extension of concrete class.  I believe this is causing you to think of the relationship backwards.  An interface, by definition, has no concrete implementation.  It only defines a contract that implementing classes must use.  Perhaps an example can help clarify.

Suppose we have an interface called `IBank`.  This interface has the following definition:

```
IBank
{
    void AddMoney(int amount);
    void RemoveMoney(int amount);
    int GetBalance();
}
```

Then we have a concrete implementation of this interface as follows:

```
EuroBank : IBank
{
    void AddMoney(int amount){ balance+= amount; }
    void RemoveMoney(int amount){ balance-= amount; }
    int GetBalance(){ return balance; }
    private int balance;
}
```

I cannot create a new instance of `IBank`.  The following code will not compile.

```
IBank bank = new IBank;
```

Instead, I must create a new concrete instance of a bank that I can treat as an `IBank`.  I can then call methods on this class.

```
IBank bank = new EuroBank;
bank.AddMoney(7);
```

So when I call `AddMoney`, I using the method defined by the interface, but I am actually calling the concrete implementation of `AddMoney` on the `EuroBank` class.

So in your example, you are calling the `m11` method on the `ab` class.  However, `ab` implements both `i11` and `i22`.  Therefore, it can be treated as both an `i11` and `i22` object.  Both of the following lines of code will work.

```
i11 first = new ab();
i22 second = new ab();
```

I can call the `m11` method on either object, but it will always use the concrete implementation of the method found on the object `ab`.

Answer (score 0):

The method is not an interface method.
The method that will be called is the `m11` method of class `ab`.